# Durandal view is accessing method with the same name in another viewmodel

Tags: durandal

I've got two different VMs that each have a few functions with the same name, such as `submitRow()`. All's well if I start in one of the views and don't leave it, but once I switch to a new view it seems like the bindings on that view are referencing the functions on the previous VM.

Obviously I can just change the function names, but I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this, or if I was even doing something wrong somewhere.

My compose settings:

```
<!--ko compose: { 
model: router.activeItem,
afterCompose: router.afterCompose,
transition:'entrance',
cacheViews:true
}--><!--/ko-->
```

A (simplified) VM:

```
define([...all my modules...],

    function(router, app, utils, ol, config, usercontext, datacontext) {
    var

/* VIEW-LEVEL VARIABLES */
        currentUserName = ko.observable();

        PIGCode = ko.observable("");
        PIGCode.isValid = ko.observable(true);
            // lots more variables...

/* DATA ACCESS METHODS */

        getOrderData = function(callback) {
            // get me my data...
        };

        // lots more methods...

    return {
        PIGCode: PIGCode,
        getOrderData: getOrderData,
        // all the other things I want to publicly expose
    };
});
```

I had forgotten about the `cacheViews` option mentioned in the comment below after having read about it in the docs a few weeks ago. It seems like turning that off might help me out. But, I'd appreciate any other feedback on my approach.

Comment: This should only happen if cache views is turned on. Please share the html compose settings and JavaScript of the vms.

Comment: Are your functions globally scoped? If they are globally scoped then yes, it can cause problems. Can you post some code?

Comment: Just edited to post some code. RainerAtSpirit, thanks for reminding me of that setting, I'll try playing around with that. @Yogesh, I'm pretty sure I've implemented my modules so that they're not globally scoped, right? :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are defining your variables improperly, thus, making them globally scoped like @Yogesh mentioned in the comments. I only see one `var` keyword in your example, yet you are putting semi-colons instead of commas after each of your variable declarations.

```
function () {
  var one = 1;   // function scoped
      two = 2;   // global scoped
      three = 3; // global scoped

  var four = 4,  // function scoped
      five = 5,  // function scoped
      six = 6;   // function scoped
}
```